# Mysql determine if update found row even if not changed

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to be able to return the number of rows found after an update even if the row did not change.  I would have thought that I  can use row_count(), however, that returns the number of rows that actually changed. So for example if I do an update on one row and the row exists but does  not change  then  row_count()  returns 0. It also can return 0 if the row does not exist. I am  particularly interested in the  case where the update uses a unique key and hence either  updates  0 rows or 1 row.

Is there  an easy  way to get the found row count after an update?

Some of the answers below describe how to do this in using php or  java, but how can it be done in a stored procedure itself (in other words if java and php is  not used)

Comment: Why not run a query before the update and count the number of rows that match the condition?

Comment: Running a query before should work in mysql, but I wanted to avoid running an additional query.  Also if autocommit is true then the row  could be deleted before the update, so a transaction would need to be started, then the query would block subsequent updates.

Answer (score 2):

It is available in the [mysqli_real_connect options](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-connect.php)

**`MYSQLI_CLIENT_FOUND_ROWS`**  return `number of matched rows, not the number of affected rows`

For java,

Statement.executeUpdate() or execute() followed by **`getUpdateCount() will return the number of rows matched`**, not updated, according to the JDBC spec.

For Stored Procedure call in Java you can use like,

```
public static void executeUpdateStoredProcedure(Connection con) {
    try {
          CallableStatement cstmt = con.prepareCall("{calldbo.UpdateTestTable(?, ?)}");
          cstmt.setString(1, "A");
          cstmt.setInt(2, 100);
          cstmt.execute();
          int count = cstmt.getUpdateCount();
          cstmt.close();

          System.out.println("ROWS AFFECTED: " + count);
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not using Php. Want  to do this either in a stored procedure or using java jdbc.  I wonder what that does under the covers?

Comment: Yes you are correct about the java. I just tested it.  Still wondering how to do this in a stored procedure.

Comment: I upticked it, but I  am still waiting to find out how to  do it in the  stored procedure itself.  In other words  calling select row_count() after doing the update in the  stored procedure

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure the following would return a variable with the value:

```
update t
    set col = if(@rn := coalesce(@rn, 0) + 1, newval, newval)
    where . . .;
```

The `if()` function needs to be evaluated before the update, regardless of whether the value is changing.

Comment: As far as I know MySQL will not physically change anything if the old and new value of a column are identical. I don't think that "hiding" the value behind an expression will work around that.